# Python Code Repetition

Tags: python, repeat

I have a lot of repetition in my code, a prime example is when I'm doing a simple check to see if the first letter of a string is a vowel or not. The code I have is as follows :

```
if word[0] == 'a' or word[0] == 'e' or word[0] == 'i' or word[0] == 'o' or word[0] == 'u':
    print 'An', word
else:
    print 'A', word
```

This works fine but the amount of repetition leads me to think there could be an easy way to shorten this, I just don't know of it. I also tried this code:

```
if word[0] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
    print 'An', word
else:
    print 'A', word
```

However, this code returned `True` for every word, regardless of beginning letter.

So, just to clarify. The code works fine and it fully functional and I know I could define it as a function and just use that but it seems like it could easily be shortened and this knowledge would be useful on multiple projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test for membership using `in`:

```
if word[0] in {"a","e","i","o","u"}
```

Also `if word[0] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'` would always evaluate to `True`, you are basically checking `if word[0] == "a"` then `if bool("e")` which will always be True for any non empty string.

Not a big deal for a small test like you are doing but [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) lookups are `0(1)` as opposed to `0(n)` for a list, string etc. so a much more efficient solution when dealing with larger data or many repeated lookups.

You can also pass a tuple or letters to `str.startswith`:

```
if word[0].startswith(("a","e","i","o","u")):
```

If you want to ignore case, call `word[0].lower()` on the letter.

Comment: And `set` that is O(1) ;)

Comment: even simpler: `if word[0] in "aeiou"` (but that is not using a `set`)

Comment: @haavee, yes, won't make much difference here but will make a considerable with larger data. Better to learn an efficient way to do something.

Answer (score 2):

Test it using the keyword `in`.

```
word = "hello"
vowels = frozenset("aeiou")

if word[0] in vowels:
    print "It's in!"
else:
    print "It's not."
```

Note that you can have your vowels in anything iterable, `set`, `list`, `string`, `dict`, a generator function or whatever you like.
As pointed out by @MartijnPieters in the comments, the `frozenset` is the most optimised way to do this.

Comment: By making `vowels` a variable you miss out on a CPython optimisation that will look up the set as a constant (stored as a `frozenset()` object with the code object) from Python 3.2 onwards. Using `if word[0] in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}` would be more efficient because of that optimisation. Here the difference will be minuscule however.

Comment: @AvinashRaj because it is one in French and I didn't pay attention :-) , MartijnPieters well like you said it's minimal but I'm glad to learn about those. Still a variable is greatly flexible!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I'll make that a frozenset then ;)

Comment: Much better; now it matches what Python'll do, and if this is inside a function then the performance will match almost exactly. The only difference is that Python creates the optimised constant just once (when loading the code object from the `.pyc` cache), while your code creates the object each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `re` module.

```
if re.match(r'(?i)[aeiou]$', word[0]):
```

This would handle both upper and lower case vowels. `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier which helps to do a case-insensitive match. Since match function tries to match the string from the begining, you dont need to add the starting anchor `^`. `[aeiou]` character class which matches a or e or i or o or u.